# Shutdown Service On GCP compute

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service, rhel7

We are trying to run a service while we delete our instance form gcp compute as shutdown service as below :-

```
[Unit]
Description=Unconfig service before shutdown
Wants=network-online.target rsyslog.service
After=network-online.target rsyslog.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
RemainAfterExit=true
#this service does nothing on satrt, and runs shutdown scripts on stop
ExecStop=/bin/bash /tmp/unconfig.sh
TimeoutStopSec=0
KillMode=process
StandardOutput=jorunal+console

[install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

We are using hostname in unconfig.sh script file. We are enabling above service on startup.while deleting GCP instance(rhel) our above service runs but the script file doesn’t execute successfully. its trying to connect to hostname but it doest not able to do this just because of session got disconnected. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi there. Why a service? SystemD was designed to keep alive processes but if you plan to run a script before the VM during the stop process you can run a [shutdown script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript).

Comment: We are not allowed to use shut down script, that’s why we are using service.

Answer (score 0):

[freedesktop.org > Soft > systemd > Running Services After the Network is up > Concepts in systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/):

> `network-online.target`. It is **strongly recommended not to pull in this target** too liberally.
>
> `network.target`. Its primary purpose is for **ordering things properly at shutdown**: since the shutdown ordering of units in systemd
> is the reverse of the startup ordering, any unit that is order
> `After=network.target` can be sure that it **is stopped before the
> network is shut down** if the system is powered off. This allows
> services to cleanly terminate connections before going down, instead
> of abruptly losing connectivity for ongoing connections, leaving them
> in an undefined state.

[freedesktop.org > Soft > systemd > systemd.special](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html):

> `network-online.target`. Note that this unit is only useful during the original system start-up logic. After the system has completed
> booting up, it will not track the online state of the system anymore.
> Due to this it cannot be used as a network connection monitor concept,
> it is purely a one-time system start-up concept.
> `network.target`. At shutdown, a unit that is ordered after `network.target` **will be stopped before the network**. It is hence
> useful when writing service files that require network access on
> shutdown.

If the goal is to let a unit to gracefully stop before the network stack is stopped, the `network.target` should be used as a dependency. Hence the configuration in the question should be changed to

```
After=network.target  
ExecStop=/tmp/unconfig.sh
```

Another approach is use of Google Compute Engine shutdown scripts, as has been already suggested by [Armando Cuevas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12010591/armando-cuevas). An advantage is that shutdown script don't have to be part of the OS image. Instead, it is stored as project or instance metadata so is centrally managed. Though existing [Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript#limitations) of GCE shutdown scripts should be taken into account:

> Compute Engine executes shutdown scripts only on a **best-effort**
> basis. In rare cases, Compute Engine cannot guarantee that the
> shutdown script will complete.

Comment: Thanks for response, we are not allowed to use shutdown script for that. That’s why decided to use a service for the purpose. Moreover we are facing issue with our process which is running on port 4444. In unconfig.sh we are trying some connection command to connect on that port. But when gcp instance is deleted our service run but when it tries to connect that port it's unable to do so. Seems like that process which was running on port 4444 killed. We want keep that process till our script executed successfully.